# Sharepoint Reporting Services on Intranet Farm

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs, wss

We have a Intranet Farm with two load balanced front end servers and a separate database, Report server is installed on box 1, so enysys data extenstions can access the sharepoint DOM.

IIS-BOX 1 + Report Server

IIS_BOX 2

SQL Server

The problem is RS fails if the user is accessing box 2, through the load balancer. If we remove Box 2 from the LB - then RS works. Put it back and it intermittently fails.

Anybody got any idea if this topology should work and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: I working this problem through - we think it is caused by RS integrated mode not working with NTLM authorization. Box 2 cannot connect to the RS on behalf of the user. Switching to Negotiate and ensuring Kerberos Authorization can take place should solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We needed to configure the iis server to use Kerberos Authentication

see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/24171/risks-involved-in-setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-wss-reporting-services) for more details

Answer (score 0):

On Box 2 are you trying to access reports that are local or load them remotely from box 1? If you are accessing them remotely from Box 1 how are you referencing it?

Also does Reporting Services work on Box 1 when accessed from the load balancer?